# How to import a dataset with Latin9 encoding in SAS Enterprise Guide 7.1

Tags: encoding, sas

I have to import a dataset (`/data/original/dataset.sas7bdat`) into SAS, and I usually use this command:

```
LIBNAME orig '/data/original/';

PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE newdataset AS SELECT * FROM orig.dataset;
RUN;
QUIT;
```

But I got this error: `ERROR: Some character data was lost during transcoding in the dataset orig.dataset. Either the data contains characters that are not representable in the new encoding or truncation occurred during transcoding.`

Using the code below I know that my sessions encoding is `utf8`.

```
PROC OPTIONS OPTION=ENCODING;
RUN;
```

And with the code below, I know the `orig.dataset`'s encoding is `latin9 European (ISO)`.

```
PROC CONTENTS DATA=orig.dataset;
RUN;
```

I tried to import the dataset with its encoding:

```
FILENAME datasetencoded '/data/original/dataset' ENCODING="LATIN9";

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=datasetencoded
OUT=newdataset
DBMS=CSV REPLACE;
GETNAMES=YES;
RUN;
```

But I got this error: `ERROR: Import unsuccessful. See SAS Log for details.`

I wonder what should I do! Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no LATIN1 character that cannot be transcoded into UTF-8.

What it most likely happening is that at least one of the resulting UTF-8 strings is longer than the variable can hold.  That could result in the converted string being truncated in the middle of multi-byte UTF-8 character.  That is what is causing the TRANSCODING error.

You can use the CVP engine to have SAS automatically expand the lengths of the variables.

https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2020/08/12/expanding-lengths-of-all-character-variables-in-sas-data-sets/

You might need to adjust the factor it uses to adjust the variable sizes to fit your data.  The default is to use CVPMULTIPLIER=1.5.  But if you have a lot of characters that need to go from single byte to double byte that might not be enough.  For LATIN1 source encoding if you use a multiplier of 3 it will always work since there are 17 LATIN1 codepoints that translate to 3 bytes in UTF-8. The others require either 1 or 2 bytes.

[image]

```
LIBNAME orig cvp '/data/original/' cvpmultiplier=3;

data newdataset;
  set orig.dataset;
run;
```